# Open par2 file?

Tags: files, compression, zip

On Ubuntu 16.04 and a program I'm trying to install downloaded a bunch of 'par2' files. Archive manager doesn't seem to recognize them. What application should I use to open these?

[image]

Comment: Could they be part of a `rar` multivolume archive? See [here](http://www.file-extensions.org/part2.rar-file-extension).

Comment: I read it wrong it was par2

Comment: I'm wondering if those files are designed to be used by the `qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.6.1.run` file to verify the integrity of downloaded files, not to be opened manually by the user... can you share what the output of the `.run` file was?

Comment: There is a `par2` package in the Ubuntu software repository, but it's designed for file verification, not extracting archives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

par and par2 files were more common in the days when Usenet was a little more popular and the parchive was intended to increase the reliability of transferring files via newsgroups.

Under Xenial Xerus you can use these files with `pypar2`:

```
sudo apt-get install pypar2
```

This give a basic gui from which to manipulate the files:

[image]

**Further Reading:**

- [Par2 Files Explained](http://www.ghacks.net/2007/05/03/par2-files-explained/)
- [Wikipedia: Parchive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive)
- [Home Page: PyPar2, a par2 frontend](http://pypar2.silent-blade.org/index.php?n=Main.HomePage)

Comment: `pypar2` is no longer in apt repo?

Comment: @Thufir Last seen in Xenial unfortunately...